# Same table size in nested tables

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, primeng

I created nested tables (primeNg component) with unknown amout of elements and this is my code:

```
    <p-table [value]="topicReports" dataKey="topicName">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th class="is-header">Topic / Comment / Author </th>
            <th class="is-header">Points</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-topic>
        <tr >
            <td>{{topic.name}}</td>
            <td >{{topic.point}}</td>
        </tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <p-table *ngIf="topic.commentReports" [value]="topic.commentReports" dataKey="commentName">
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-comment>
                    <tr clas="background-color">
                        <td class="pl-4">{{comment.name}}</td>
                        <td >{{comment.point}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <p-table *ngIf="comment.authorReports" [value]="comment.authorReports" dataKey="authorName">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-author>
                                <tr *ngIf="author.point > 0" >
                                    <td class="pl-5">{{author.name}}</td>
                                    <td >{{author.point}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-table>
                    </td>
                </ng-template>
            </p-table>
        </td>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="summary">
        <div style="text-align: right">
            Summary points: {{summaryPoints}}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

And this how it looks like now:

[image: picture]

Like in the picture, nested child table have smaller size than parent.
What I try to do is create maybe some kind of CSS to make them same responsive size.

After discussion with @LGSon I'll provide as much text code as it's possible.
But before I even start I need to tell you, that I used [PrimeNg table component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table), this means you probably cannot run this example without [PrimeNg installation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)

So i updated my html file(by removing all non important parts)

This is my `.ts` file:

```
export class TopicComponent implements OnInit {

  testCustomerReports: TopicReport[] = [];
  testCommentReports: CommentReport[] = [];
  testAuthorReports: AuthorReport[] = [];
  summaryPoints: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.summaryPoints = 22;
    this.testAuthorReports = [new AuthorReport("Test topic", 22)];
    this.testCommentReports = [new CommentReport("Test comment", 22, this.testAuthorReports)];
    this.customerReports = [new TopicReport("Test author", 22, this.testCommentReports)];
  }
}
```

Those are my objects:

```
import { CommentReport } from "./comment-report";

export class AuthorReport {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public points: number,
    public CommentReports: CommentReport[]
  ) {  }
}

import { AuthorReport } from "./author-report";

export class CommentReport {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public points: number,
    public authorReports: AuthorReport[]
  ) {  }
}

export class AuthorReport {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public points: number
  ) {  }
}
```

My CSS file is clear (totally clear, nothing inside, because all css are probably `build-in` in `p-table` component from `PrimeNg`.

I need to say, that I also tried to inspect by my web browser,  but I didn't found anything that could point for any padding property, but I'm not sure if I did it right.
I pressed right on element, than inspect and I was searching for something similar to padding in style view, but didnt found anything. and this is what I found there:

[image: first]
[image: second]

Update 28.11.2018:

Changes suggested by  @Kosh Very in his answer made a table look like this:

[image: after suggestion]

Now there is a visible table in table in table and I just wanted to make my nested tables to be a row in my first table (like in my first example, but without this indentation).

Second update after comment by @Kosh Very.

> Why do I use nested tables?

(I'm not sure if you need to know, but I dont know how many topics are in a table, and I don't know how many comments have single topic, and how many comments have single comment).

I was trying to do it without nested tables as:

```
<div *ngIf="tableGenerated">
    <div class="pt-4">
        <p-table [value]="topicReports" dataKey="topicName">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                    <th class="is-header"> topic / comment / author</th>
                    <th class="is-header"> points</th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-topic>
                <tr class="background-color">
                    <td>{{topic.name}}</td>
                    <td class="is-number">{{topic.point}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="background-color">
                    <td>{{topic.commentReports.name}}</td>
                    <td class="is-number">{{topic.commentReports.point}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="background-color">
                    <td>{{topic.commentReports.authorReports.name}}</td>
                    <td class="is-number">{{topic.commentReports.authorReports.point}}</td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it seems like I cannot do something like: `topic.commentReports.authorReports.point` Thats why I made nested tables.

Comment: Table cells has a default padding that most likely is the reason. If you want a more exact reply, provide the rendered HTML and its CSS as a [mcve], as we can't debug an _image_.

Comment: @LGSon p-table is angular/primeNg table component and I think html+css won't be enough to just run/debug it.

Comment: Since your markup will depend on the set CSS, and we can't see that as you didn't post it, it is highly relevant. Did you inspect the rendered result using the browser's dev. tools? ... as that would most likely show what goes on.

Comment: Well CSS is empty (seems like angular/primeNg/p-table has his own CSS, so I think I need to overwrite some CSS properties. But like you offered I investigated column and didnt found anything that could point for some of padding, but its quite good idea. I'll investigate it once again, and I'll take a screenshot. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Do note, we do not want _screenshots_, we want code as text.

Comment: Ok, I'll provide you as much text code as its possible.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: @lharby I was using console and I was inspecting that field, but didnt found anything that could change the place of those tables.

Comment: @degath all of the css properties of the table will be available in the front end and can be inspected in the console. Even if no properties are explicitly set there are defaults that are built into the browser.

Comment: Ah OK you have posted your console. So try removing border-spacing, or setting it to 0px.

Comment: Click on computed and then you can see all the properties for that element, you can see what properties are inherited. You may have to start from the cell and work upwards.

Comment: @lharby I tried, seems like nothing point for that. I'm thinking that this behavior is default for that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template code is incorrect:
HTML table cells `<td>` need to be placed into rows `<tr>`, but you missed some.

Also, you cannot place `<div>` into `<table>` directly.
So you need to wrap it into a cell, then wrap the cell into a row, and then place the row into the table.

Final solution found by @degath:

```
<p-table [value]="topicReports" dataKey="topicName">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th>task / comment / author</th>
      <th>points </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-topic>
    <tr class="background-color">
      <td>{{topic.name}}</td>
      <td class="is-number">{{topic.workedHour}}</td>
    </tr>
    <ng-template ngFor let-comment [ngForOf]="topic.commentReports">
      <tr class="background-color">
        <td class="pl-4">{{comment.name}}</td>
        <td class="is-number">{{comment.workedHour}}</td>
      </tr>
      <ng-template ngFor let-author [ngForOf]="comment.authorReports">
        <tr class="background-color">
          <td class="pl-4">{{author.name}}</td>
          <td class="is-number">{{author.workedHour}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for your time! I updated a question for you.

Comment: @degath, thank you for the update! So why don't you just remove the nested tables?

Comment: Good question! I'll answer my question once again.

Comment: @degath, I've updated my answer with the flattened template.

Comment: I updated my answer, but it looks like you're reading in my mind. I think that you already made my day.... It looks like it's what I'm looking for. I'll accept the answer ASAP if it will work like expected.

Comment: @degath, sorry, I've updated it once again to support nested loops in comments and their replies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184426/discussion-between-degath-and-kosh-very).

Comment: check discussion once again.